# What are the differences among ETO, ETA, and ELDT?

Tags: air-traffic-control, time

We are analyzing the Arrival Manager (AMAN) logs and would like to have an understanding of the difference between Estimated Time for Arrival (ETA), Estimated Time Over (ETO), and Estimated Landing Time (ELDT). Are they calculated based on different reference points?

Comment: Please help us understand the question better by defining your acronyms.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestions. Here are the definitions of my acronyms. ETA: Estimated Time for Arrival, ETO: Estimated Time Over, ELDT: Estimated Landing Time. Those Acronyms are from the Arrival Manager (AMAN) system, not sure if they are standard lingos among other systems, or specifically defined for the AMAN system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ETO is the estimated time over a certain point, probably some sort of arrival fix defined in your AMAN, such as the beginning of the arrival route.

ETA is the estimated time over the initial approach fix or overhead the aerodrome.

ELDT is the estimated time of crossing the threshold of the landing runway.